# Oracle. Select and function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IntervalToSec(Run_Duration interval day to second) RETURN NUMBER IS
vSeconds NUMBER ;
BEGIN 
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY    FROM Run_Duration ) * 86400
     + EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM Run_Duration ) *  3600
     + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM Run_Duration ) *    60
     + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM Run_Duration )
  INTO
    vSeconds 
  FROM DUAL ;
  RETURN vSeconds ;
END;
```

That converts interval data to total seconds number
Then i have select query:

```
select RUN_DURATION  from SYS.USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS WHERE JOB_NAME = 'WASTE_MESSAGES_JOB' and LOG_DATE > (systimestamp - INTERVAL '0 00:10:00.0'DAY TO SECOND(1) )  
order by LOG_DATE desc;
```

Output like:+00 00:00:01.000000
Question is how can i pipe query result into function?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [user defined function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions256.htm#SQLRF06181) doesn't behave any differently to [built-in functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions001.htm#SQLRF51173), so you call it as you would any other function - to_char, to_date, trunc, round etc.

> You can write user-defined functions in PL/SQL, Java, or C to provide functionality that is not available in SQL or SQL built-in functions. User-defined functions can appear in a SQL statement wherever an expression can occur.
>
> For example, user-defined functions can be used in the following:
>
> - The select list of a SELECT statement
> - ...

So just call the function as part of the query:

```
select IntervalToSec(RUN_DURATION)
from SYS.USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
WHERE JOB_NAME = 'WASTE_MESSAGES_JOB'
and LOG_DATE > (systimestamp - INTERVAL '0 00:10:00.0'DAY TO SECOND(1) )  
order by LOG_DATE desc;
```

As long as the queried column is the same data type the function expects (or can be implicitly converted to that type) it can be passed as the function's argument.

Comment: O my.....Thats was so easy but i cant even :google: corrext syntax!!!! Alex thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm

I believe a select Into statement will work for this? If you just want the query results to go into the function statement. Parameters for the into say it will take a function_name. Of course I could be way off as I've  never used it for getting information into functions.